# Boot layer java.lang.LayerInstantiationException when package exists in two modules

Tags: java

Getting below error while running main application or JUnit5 test case -

"**Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package test in both module mainAppModule and libModule**"

This error is reported when "resources" folder has a **non-empty** "**test**" folder under it.  If "**test**" folder is **empty**, or **doesnt exist**, this **error** is **not reported**.

Setup is:

1. Env - Windows 10, OpenJDK 13, Eclipse 2020-03, Maven is 3.6.3.
2. libModule has src/main/java and src/test/java folders.  "resources" folder is at the level of "src" folder.
3. "resources" folder has properties.xml file.
4. libModule has a dummy main class.  It refers properties file from "resources" and works correctly.
5. libModule has JUnit5 test class too.  properties.xml for JUnit5 test case is kept under "resource/test" folder.  This JUnit5 test case runs correctly.

Things are good upto this point.  Lets look at setup of main app module.

mainAppModule uses libModule.  module-info.java of mainAppModule contains "requires libModule".  mainAppModule has same setup of src, test and resources folder as that of libModule, ie "src/main/java" for java source, "src/test/java" for JUnit5 test cases and "resources" for resource files.

main app in mainAppModule populates properties from xml file under its "resources" folder and invokes libModule class.  This works when "test" folder doesnt exist under "resources" or even if exists, it is empty.

As soon as non-empty "test" folder is created under "resources" folder, above error is reported.

Like main app, JUnit5 test case from mainAppModule fails for the exact same reason.  Test case too succeeds if "test" folder doesnt exist under "resources" or if exists, it is empty.

Above error is reported even before hitting main () method.  Questions are:

1. What's wrong with non-empty "test" folder under "resources"?
2. How to debug such scenario where exception occurs before reaching main ()?

Workaround to this is to use any folder name other than "test".   Functionality works correctly if "test" is renamed to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Excluding "test" folder from jar packaging of the libModule solved this problem.  From my side, I'm happy with this approach and no further details needed now.

Answer (score 0):

I was running with following command to run the module app:

```
D:\work\mymodapp> java --module-path appmodules --module appstart/appstart.mymodappdemo.MyModAppDemo

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package appstart.mymodappdemo in both module appstart and module appfuncs
```

this was error caused, I resolved it with this command:

```
D:\work\mymodapp>java --module-path appmodules -m appfuncs/appstart.mymodappdemo.MyModAppDemo
2 is factor of 10
Simple factor common to both 35 and 105 is: 5
Largest factor common to both 35 and 105 is: 35
```

I followed java complete reference 11e, there was mistake there and corrected it this way:

You need to create 2 modules:
[Directory structure for simple modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A67aT.png)

```
D:\work\mymodapp>javac -d appmodules\appfuncs appsrc\appfuncs\appfuncs\simplefuncs\SimpleMathFuncs.java

D:\work\mymodapp>javac -d appmodules\appfuncs appsrc\appfuncs\module-info.java

D:\work\mymodapp>javac --module-path appmodules -d appmodules\appstart appsrc\appstart\module-info.java appsrc\appstart\appstart\mymodappdemo\MyModAppDemo.java

D:\work\mymodapp>java --module-path appmodules -m appfuncs/appstart.mymodappdemo.MyModAppDemo
```

Code:
//MyModAppDemo.java:

```
package appstart.mymodappdemo;


import appfuncs.simplefuncs.SimpleMathFuncs;

public class MyModAppDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            if(SimpleMathFuncs.isFactor(2, 10)){
                System.out.println("2 is factor of 10");
            }
            
            System.out.println("Simple factor common to both 35 and 105 is: "+SimpleMathFuncs.lcf(35, 105));
            
            System.out.println("Largest factor common to both 35 and 105 is: "+SimpleMathFuncs.gcf(35, 105));
            
        }

}
```

---

```
//SimpleMathFuncs.java:

package appfuncs.simplefuncs;

public class SimpleMathFuncs {
    //Determine if a is factor of b
    public static boolean isFactor(int a, int b){
        if((b % a) == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    public static int lcf(int a, int b){
        //factor using positive values:
        a = Math.abs(a);
        b = Math.abs(b);
        
        int min = a < b ? a : b;
        
        for(int i = 2;i <= min/2; i++ ){
            if(isFactor(i, a) && isFactor(i, b))
                return i;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    
    public static int gcf(int a, int b){
        //factor using positive values:
        a = Math.abs(a);
        b = Math.abs(b);
        
        int min = a < b ? a : b;
        
        for(int i = min/2;i >= 2; i++ ){
            if(isFactor(i, a) && isFactor(i, b))
                return i;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

//module-info.java, at appstart module:

```
module appstart {
    //Requires the module appfuncs
    requires appfuncs;
}
```

---

```
//module-info.java, at appfuncs module:

module appfuncs {
        //Exports the package appfuncs.simplefuncs
        exports appfuncs.simplefuncs;
    }
```

Hopefully this complete example helps.